# Query for getting students and grades SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a students table Student(LRN,fName,lName,levelID) and a grade table GRADE(subjectID,grade,levelID,LRN,TimeAdded) I want to show all students with all of thier subjects with grades in on line. I tired this query but I got this results.

```
Query: SELECT student.LRN, student.fName, student.lName, 
(SELECT grade.grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2arts') AS 'k2arts',
(SELECT grade.grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2math') AS 'k2math',
(SELECT grade.grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2eng') AS 'k2eng',
(SELECT grade.grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2valed') AS 'k2valed',
(SELECT grade.grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2fil') AS 'k2fil' 
from student RIGHT JOIN grade on grade.LRN=student.LRN
```

Results:
[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRTSh.png)

Comment: Yes its is. Grade.LRN is a foreign key to Student.LRN

Comment: And???  What's the question???  What's wrong with your query???  What's wrong with the result???  We can't help if we don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to establish the relationship of the STUDENT in each subquery. You do not need to join in `Grade` in the main query since you aren't using any of its values except by way of subqueries, which are in an unrelated context in this case:

```
SELECT student.LRN, student.fName, student.lName, 
(SELECT grade.grade FROM grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2arts' AND grade.LRN=st.LRN) AS 'k2arts',
(SELECT grade.grade FROM grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2math' AND grade.LRN=st.LRN) AS 'k2math',
(SELECT grade.grade FROM grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2eng' AND grade.LRN=st.LRN) AS 'k2eng',
(SELECT grade.grade FROM grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2valed' AND grade.LRN=st.LRN) AS 'k2valed',
(SELECT grade.grade FROM grade WHERE grade.subjectID = 'k2fil' AND grade.LRN=st.LRN) AS 'k2fil' 
from student st
```

Comment: Do yo know why I get a "Unknown column grade.grade in field list"?

Comment: Yes. Because you were missing the FROM clause in your subqueries (and so was I). I have updated my answer. Do consider @ScaisEdge's answer below since it only requires a single join and a kind of fakey aggregation (fake because nothing is actually being aggregated, but it will cause a single record to be outputted instead of 5 for each LRN), it will probably be more efficient.

Comment: Yes I think so. But I always get a case not recognized error

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join and a case when

```
SELECT student.LRN, student.fName, student.lName, 
  case when grade.subjectID = 'k2arts' then grade.grade else null end AS 'k2arts',
  case when grade.subjectID = 'k2math' then grade.grade else null end AS 'k2math',
  case when grade.subjectID = 'k2eng' then grade.grade else null end AS 'k2eng',
  case when grade.subjectID = 'k2valed' then grade.grade else null end AS 'k2valed',
  case when grade.subjectID = 'k2fil' then grade.grade else null end AS 'k2fil'
from student 
LEFT JOIN grade on grade.LRN=student.LRN
```

and eventually use a fake aggregation function for remove null

```
SELECT student.LRN, student.fName, student.lName, 
  min(case when grade.subjectID = 'k2arts' then grade.grade else null end) AS 'k2arts',
  min(case when grade.subjectID = 'k2math' then grade.grade else null end) AS 'k2math',
  min(case when grade.subjectID = 'k2eng' then grade.grade else null end) AS 'k2eng',
  min(case when grade.subjectID = 'k2valed' then grade.grade else null end) AS 'k2valed',
  min(case when grade.subjectID = 'k2fil' then grade.grade else null end) AS 'k2fil'
from student  student.LRN, student.fName, student.lName
LEFT JOIN grade on grade.LRN=student.LRN 
group by
```

Comment: I get a case not recognized error when I try your query

Comment: It's missing the `THEN` keyword.

Comment: `case when grade.subjectID = 'k2arts' then grade.grade else null end AS 'k2arts'`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT student.LRN, student.fName, student.lName, 
CASE WHEN grade.subjectID = 'k2arts' THEN grade.grade END AS 'k2arts',
CASE WHEN grade.subjectID = 'k2math'  THEN grade.grade END AS 'k2math',
CASE WHEN grade.subjectID = 'k2eng'   THEN grade.grade END AS 'k2eng',
CASE WHEN grade.subjectID = 'k2valed' THEN grade.grade END AS 'k2valed',
CASE WHEN grade.subjectID = 'k2fil'   THEN grade.grade END AS 'k2fil' 
from student 
LEFT JOIN grade 
on grade.LRN=student.LRN ;
```